# Ajax success display message in console

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I have data in an array which is supposed to be sent to a php file using ajax.
I have tried to use console.log to display the array being sent and also to display a message if the data was successfully sent.However no message is being displayed on my console.Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
 var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),

    data = {};
    var cart = {};

    cart.item_name = miniform.elements['itemId'].value;
    cart.quantity = miniform.elements['quantityId'].value;
    cart.amount = miniform.elements['amountId'].value;
    cart.total = amount * quantity;

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(cart);

   $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data:{data:jsonString},
    success: function(){
        console.log('Email Sent');
     }
    });
 console.log(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Try it like this and see what you get -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vfvr7gvv/

Comment: @adeneo still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, it is hard to say what is wrong without cheking out your console/backend. I assume that you want to send an email from the server using some data you have collected from a form and both your backend script and frontend script are located on the same domain. So, what could you do?

1. First, check whether your function that is supposed to send data gets
   actually triggered (place something like `alert('test')` at the
   beginning of that function); It is suspicious indeed that you get
   nothing in the console. Maybe you know it but you have to assign a function (handler) to your action if you want some work to be done. I mean there should be a click event handler inside which you should place all that JS stuff. The existence of such a handler isn't evident from the piece of code you shared. Something like this: `$('.form_submit_btn').on('click', function() { // all your code goes here});`
2. Check that the backend script actually works and an email is sent.
       Try to call that script directly through an url;
3. Check that the frontend script is actually sending data and is able
       to get the result. Create a simple backend script that just
       outputs something like "Hello world!" and change the url in your AJAX
       call to it;
4. Add error handler to your AJAX function;

Although I would like to mention that this line:

```
 cart.total = amount * quantity;
```

looks strange to me. Do you actually have such variables? Shouldn't they be `cart.amount` and `cart.quantity` respectively?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used your first answer for using alert and found where the problem was in my code.Thanks again

Comment: You were also right about the cart.total......the variables should be cart.amount and cart.quantity for those who wondered about the same

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what is happening is that you are not retuning an actual success message and that is why it is not being logged. Instead of the `success` function in your AJAX call, change it to `always` and see if you get the results back. You will also need to add a parameter to your `always` function which will be your response, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: type,
  data:{data:jsonString},
  always: function(result){
    console.log('Email Sent');
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

As pointed out in the comments, you should have an `error` callback as well so that you can always know if you have an error. That would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: type,
  data:{data:jsonString},
  success: function(result){
    console.log('Email Sent');
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: function(error){
    throw new Error('Did not work');
  }
});
```

If you can show your PHP, we can help with that and get you back a `success` response.

**EDIT**
Use your dev tools in your browser to see if your request is being made:

[image]

Also, check out this JSBin for a working example of an AJAX request: https://jsbin.com/wazanuwuge/edit?js,console

Comment: I have tried your code but still nothing is being dispayed in console

Comment: @lorrainemutheu Did you try it with the updated `always` function? Is there anything in the console at all? What does your PHP look like?

Comment: I was able to get it to work with my project. I just need to get the actual error returned instead of "did not work". Thanks.